# Left join multiple tables onto one table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to left join multiple tables to one table. The tables are themselves results of subqueries.

A classical example that comes to my mind is, I have a bunch of subqueries:
1. Subquery A gives me details of students  - say table 1
2. Subquery B gives me student scores in Math  - say table 2
3. Subquery C gives me student scores in English  - say table 3
The tables contain scores only if the student has taken that test and the student is to be considered failed if he/she has not taken test at all (or has a score < passing score). I have student IDs (unique per person) in each table to join on.

What do I want from these?  I am trying to build a dynamic query (where some parts are populated at runtime by an external mechanism) by performing some joins on these tables to give me:
1. Students who passed in both tests and corresponding scores
2. Students passed in either test, but failed (or did not take) the other test and the corresponding scores (NULL if not taken).
3. All students and their corresponding scores.

What I have on mind is left joining **each** score table **to student profile table**.  How should I go about this?

Before you go ahead and suggest `table 1 left join table 2 left join table 3`, this structure will cause problems if, say table 2 contains a null record for a particular student (as per my knowledge). And this basically joins table 3 on table 2 and not on table 1, from my understanding, which is what I want.

PS: Feel free to suggest better ways to get what I need, if you know any.

Comment: Well as it seems like home work, you should put your attempts. Then some one here will help you to fix what is wrong on it.

Comment: _"this basically joins table 3 on table 2 and not on table 1 which is what I want"_ - no, it joins to the resultset of the previous join. And since previous join is _left outer_, it will contain all rows of the `table 1` even when there is no corresponding row in `table 2`. The ON clause doesn't have to contain fields from `table 2` - it can contain fields from `table 1`, so you can equate them with fields from `table 3` directly.

Comment: Its not homework. @Branko: Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create the appropriate relations by writing carefully your query:

```
select 
    t1.*, t2.foo, t3.bar
from
    table1 as t1
    left join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    left join table3 as t3 on t1.id = t3.id
```

As you can see, `table3` is related to `table1` (not to `table2`), which is what you want.

Comment: Ohh yeah. I though you cannot access table 1 alias after joining it onto table 2

Comment: As I said, you can create the appropriate relations by writing carefully your query. That means: *any relations*. You can of course create very complex relations... but I  suggest you keep things simple.